# Want to run Sharepoint/Powershell tools on local machine - what do I need?

Tags: 2010, powershell

My local machine is not a SP server, but i want to be able to run powershell and connect to a SP 2010 server to administer it.  What do I need to install locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this post [SharePoint 2010 with Windows PowerShell Remoting Step by Step](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310173834/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/opal/archive/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step.aspx) covered everything. Are you looking for something particular?

If you are using XP then you can download PowerShell from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110616023338/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6ccb7e0d-8f1d-4b97-a397-47bcc8ba3806). If you are using Windows 7 then it come with PowerShell installed.

Comment: Ok, that probably does answer my question, but I'm trying to get it to work to see if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to enable remote powershell on the remote machine. After connecting, the sharepoint pssnapin needs to be loaded,